# Can't Upload Patch - Previously Deprecated Components Recognized as New, Can't Delete Them Either

Tags: managed-package, patch

I can't upload a patch because, as the error says:

> A patch version cannot contain any new components. The list below indicates which components you must remove before proceeding with the upload.

The problem, however, is that I can't remove the deprecated components. How am I supposed to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You simply can't do that on a patch. Patches are designed to fix bugs, and therefore you can only touch code, not metadata.

From the documentation (note that the word "added", in most cases, also applies to deletions)

> Development in a patch development organization is restricted.
>
> The following is a list of caveats:
>
> New package components can’t be added.
>
> Existing package components can’t be deleted.
>
> API and dynamic Apex access controls can’t change for the package.
>
> No deprecation of any Apex code.
>
> No new Apex class relationships, such as extends, can be added.
>
> No new Apex access modifiers, such as virtual or global, can be added.
>
> No new Web services can be added. No new feature dependencies can be added.

If you want to delete the deprecated components, you're going to have to do so in a new version of the package.

Look at some documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_patches_about.htm) and [here, in the 2nd paragraph](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_patches_creating.htm)

Comment: It seems like this is a Salesforce bug, then, that deprecated components in patch versions would be recognized as new components. I saw [this post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1494/problems-with-deprecation-in-patch-to-minor-release-of-managed-package) which describes the same bug in Oct of 2012. I guess it takes at least five years for Salesforce to fix simple issues.